Pass argument to npm scripts with pnpm
I have this setup with npm and webpack
    "start:env": "npm-run-all copy lint \"webpack:dev -- --config webpack/{1}.config.js\" --",

I'm calling this like so
╰─ npm run start:env uat-local                                                                                                                                                  

Here's my vite and pnpm setup
    "start:env": "vite dev --config build-config/{1}.config.js",

I'm trying to call this like so
╰─ pnpm run start:env uat-local                                                                                                                                                  

The problem is that script does not read {1} from the terminal

vite --config build-config/${1}.config.js "uat-local"
✘ [ERROR] Could not resolve "/home/alex/work/.../build-config/.config.js"


Hello, so it seems pnpm does not support that at the moment, that was confirmed by the author here https://github.com/orgs/pnpm/discussions/4844 The answer is two years old but I haven't found anything that says it is possible. The closest I could get to the behavior above is by using inlinecenv variables
"start": "profile=local pnpm start:env",
"start:env": "vite --config build/config/${profile}.config.js",
in console:
profile=PROFILE pnpm start:env
